# How to use dplyr's enquo and quo_name in a function with tidyr and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

```
library(dplyr) #Devel version, soon-to-be-released 0.6.0
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats) #for gss_cat data
```

I'm attempting to write a function that combines quosures from the soon-to-be-released `dplyr` devel version together with `tidyr::gather` and `ggplot2`. So far it seems to work with `tidyr`, but I'm having trouble with the plotting.

The below function seems to work with `tidyr's gather`:

```
GatherFun<-function(gath){
  gath<-enquo(gath)

  gss_cat%>%select(relig,marital,race,partyid)%>%
    gather(key,value,-!!gath)%>%
    count(!!gath,key,value)%>%
    mutate(perc=n/sum(n))
}
```

But I can't figure out how to make the plots work. I tried using `!!gath` with `ggplot2`, but it didn't work.

```
GatherFun<-function(gath){
  gath<-enquo(gath)

  gss_cat%>%select(relig,marital,race,partyid)%>%
    gather(key,value,-!!gath)%>%
    count(!!gath,key,value)%>%
    mutate(perc=n/sum(n))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=value,y=perc,fill=!!gath))+
       geom_col()+
       facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") +
       geom_text(aes(x = "value", y = "perc", 
                     label = "perc", group = !!gath),
                 position = position_stack(vjust = .05))
}
```

Comment: My answer to this more recent question applies: [Use dplyr SE with ggplot2] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279287/use-dplyr-se-with-ggplot2/47044567#47044567). In a nutshell, I recommend you use aes_(x=~value, y=~perc, fill=gath). The syntax is cleaner than using aes_string when you already have quosures in play.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel like the main problem is `ggplot` is greedy when it tries to evaluate `!!gath` and does `!(!gath)`, throwing an error as `not(gath)` has no meaning. I've has this issue crop up a lot when I've tried to use `!!` so I'm kinda weary about using it in its sugar form.

If someone more precise could correctly identify the problem it would definitely be helpful.

```
gather_func = function(gath) {

  gath = enquo(gath)

  gss_cat %>%
    select(relig, marital, race, partyid) %>%
    gather(key, value, -!!gath) %>%
    count(!!gath, key, value) %>%
    mutate(perc = round(n/sum(n), 2)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = perc, fill = eval(rlang::`!!`(gath)))) +
    geom_col() + 
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        x = value, 
        y = perc, 
        label = perc, 
        group = eval(rlang::`!!`(gath))
      ),
      position = position_stack(vjust = .05)
    )
}
```

There seems to be a few mistakes in the function call you wrote in the question. properly spacing your code will help avoid that.

You also don't have you use the `rlang` call, I just don't have the newest `dplyr` version installed.

**EDIT** Some thoughts using a simpler `mtcars` example:

Tbh I'm quite unsure of what's going on here, but I imagine it's to do with the fact the `ggplot2` is relatively old now and has a slightly different design? Stepping into `aes` with `debug`, we find a structure similar to

```
structure(list(x = mpg, y = eval(rlang::UQE(var))), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), class = "uneval")
```

(This won't run through the interpreter but is roughly what the structure looks like). I think this shows why the `eval` call is necessary here, o/w ggplot is trying to map `rlang::UQE(var)` to the `y` aesthetic and reports it doesn't know what to do with something of class `name`. `eval` evaluates the name to, say, `cyl`, then the aesthetic can be mapped as normal.

I imagine `dplyr` verbs don't have this extra mapping step where the arguments are manipulated into some intermediate structure in the same way, so we don't have this issue.

Also, when I said you don't have to use the `rlang` call, it was because I assumed this function was re-exported into the new `dplyr` version. Because of the whole `!!(...)` or `!(!(...))` thing I mentioned earlier, I prefer to use `rlang::"!!"`, or `rlang::UQE` (which are exactly equivalent I believe).

Most of this is speculation though and if someone could correct me on anything I've got wrong it would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So  when you say I don't have to use the rlang call, do I still use  - fill=eval(`!!`(gath)))) ? Can you elaborate a bit more on this? Also, what does the "eval" do? I'm still new to SE and NSE so any extra details would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Added an edit making some guesses at why NSE doesn't work as intended here. Some of the things above seem to break conventions outlined in the NSE vignette here: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, hence I feel like `ggplot` may be slightly out of scope of the article, due to its age

Answer (score 13):

In order to make this work I had to use `dplyr::quo_name` to change the quosure into a string. I also had to use `ggplot2::aes_string`, which also requires all the inputs to be strings, and therefore quoted with `""`.

```
GatherFun <- function(gath){
  gath <- enquo(gath)
  gathN <- quo_name(gath)

  gss_cat %>% 
    select(relig, marital, race, partyid) %>%
    gather(key, value, -!!gath) %>%
    count(!!gath, key, value) %>%
    mutate(perc = round(n/sum(n), 2)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes_string(x = "value", y = "perc", fill = gathN)) +
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") +
    geom_text(aes_string(x = "value", y = "perc", label = "perc", group = gathN), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = .05))
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using ggplot2::aes_string?

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the accepted answer

Comment: @Andrie I agree. I posted that after OP's comment of how to do it w/o aes_string

Answer (score 4):

It's now possible to use tidy evaluation inside `aes` in [`ggplot2 v3.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/). Thus `aes_string` is no longer needed.

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)

library(tidyverse) 

GatherFun2 <- function(gath) {

  gath <- enquo(gath)

  gss_cat %>% 
    select(relig, marital, race, partyid) %>%
    gather(key, value, -!! gath) %>%
    count(!!gath, key, value) %>%
    mutate(perc = round(n/sum(n), 2)) %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_col(aes(x = value, y = perc, fill = !! gath)) +
      facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
      xlab(NULL) +
      geom_text(aes(x = value, y = perc, 
                    label = ifelse(perc == 0, "", perc), 
                    group = !! gath), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = .2)) +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1.0)) 
}

GatherFun2(marital)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question elsewhere recently ([Use dplyr SE with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279287/use-dplyr-se-with-ggplot2/47044567#47044567)).  Not sure how to mark duplicates so I will repeat here.

> If you are already handling quosures the syntax is cleaner if you use
>   `aes_` rather than `aes_string`.

This bit of code should work in your example. Notice that all the hard-coded variables (value, perc, key) are quoted with a tilda while the quosure (gath) is used directly.

```
ggplot(aes_(x = ~value, y = ~perc, fill = gath) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(aes_(x = ~value, y = ~perc, label = ~perc, group = gath),
            position = position_stack(vjust = .05))
```