# Use dplyr SE with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I often combine `dplyr` with `ggplot2` in wrapper functions for analysis. As I am moving to the new NSE / SE paradigm of v.0.7.1 with `tidyeval`, I am struggling to get this combination to work. I found that `ggplot` does not understand unquoted quosers (yet). The following does not work:

```
example_func <- function(col) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  mtcars %>% count(!!col) %>% 
    ggplot(aes((!!col), n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}
example_func(cyl)
# Error in !col : invalid argument type
```

I currently use the following work-around. But I assume there must be a better way.

```
example_func2 <- function(col) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  mtcars %>% count(!!col) %>% 
    ggplot(aes_string(rlang::quo_text(col), "n")) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}
```

Please show me what the best way to combine these two. Thanks!

Comment: If it is a string, you need `aes_string`,  What is the issue with that one?

Comment: It feels like a big detour, quoting, then using quo_text, then using aes_string. Hoped there was a more straightforward solution.

Comment: Yet, this [seems to be the way to go](http://colinfay.me/tidyeval-1/) when using tidyeval.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already handling quosures it's easier to use `aes_` which accepts inputs quoted as a formula: `aes_(col, ~n)`.

This bit of code solves your problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
example_func <- function(col) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  mtcars %>% count(!!col) %>% 
    ggplot(aes_(col, ~n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}

example_func(cyl)
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two ways of thinking about this.

### Approach 1: Separation of concerns.

I like my plotting stuff to be very much separate from my wrangling stuff. Also, you can name your group which feels like the easiest method to solve your problem [although you do loose the original column name]. So one method of solving what you're trying to do can be via;

```
library(tidyverse)

concern1_data <- function(df, col) {
  group <- enquo(col)
  df %>% 
    group_by(group = !!group) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}

concern2_plotting <- function(df){
  ggplot(data=df) +
    geom_bar(aes(group, n), stat = "identity")
}

mtcars %>% 
  concern1_data(am) %>% 
  concern2_plotting()
```

This achieves what you're trying to do more or less and keeps concerns apart (which deserves a mention).

## Approach 2: Accept and Wait

> Thing is: tidyeval is not yet implemented in ggplot2.
>   - Colin Fay [from link](http://colinfay.me/tidyeval-1/)

I think this is support that is currently not in ggplot2 but I can't imagine that ggplot2 won't get this functionality. It's just not there yet.

Comment: I found out that indeed the tidyeval will be coming to ggplot soon. I like your two step approach, only drawback in this example is that you loose the column name on the plot, but that is of course easily fixed.