# Why does this aes tidyeval example from ggplot documentation throw an error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to write a wrapper function around ggplot, but I keep coming up with an error when unquoting a function parameter:

```
Error in !enquo(x) : invalid argument type
```

I have re-read the dplyr programming guide, and thought I understood it and have used tidyeval previously in implementing functions using dplyr verbs eg group_by and mutate. This brought me to the [ggplot documentation for aes](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html) where I found this example:

```
scatter_by <- function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(!!enquo(x), !!enquo(y)))
}
scatter_by(mtcars, disp, drat)
```

When I run this in RStudio 1.1.383, I get the error:

```
Error in !enquo(x) : invalid argument type
```

I am using ggplot2 version 2.2.1 and dplyr 0.7.4

I have tried using rlang::UQ(enquo(x)) instead of !! but I still get an error.

Comment: Your code seems fine and it worked as well on my pc, I am using ggplot version : `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`

Comment: Using tidyeval in ggplot2 is a feature that will be part of the [next release](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#ggplot2-2219000), which I believe is imminent. You can install the development version [from github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2#ggplot2-) if you'd like to use that feature now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aes_string` and `quo_name`.

```
scatter_by <- function(data, x, y) {

  ggplot(data) + 
    geom_point(aes_string(x= quo_name(enquo(x)), y=quo_name(enquo(y))))

}
scatter_by(mtcars, disp, drat)
```

Here is quite substantial disscusion about this problem: [How to use dplyr's enquo and quo_name in a function with tidyr and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405843/how-to-use-dplyrs-enquo-and-quo-name-in-a-function-with-tidyr-and-ggplot2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and link. aes should support tidyeval without needing to use aes_string, should it not? This has made my wrapper function work, I would just like a tidier version

Comment: According to the documentation it should but apparently it does not work. I checked it on dplyr 0.7.4 and 0.7.5 without success. Maybe it is worth to report it on ggplot2's github?